# `Carbon->timestamp` but without seconds

Tags: php, timestamp, php-carbon

There is any **`Carbon` way** to get the timestamp of a `Carbon` object, but without seconds?

I need to compare two `Carbon` objects, but I don't want to consider the seconds...

```
if ($carbon1->timestamp > $carbon2->timestamp) {
   // Do something...
}
```

I prefer to not use solutions like

```
$timestampWithoutSeconds = substr($carbon1->timestamp, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your timestamp is in milliseconds you could just substract the seconds from it.

Let's say your timestamp is 1564562500699, which is Wed Jul 31 2019 10:41:40 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

```
$timestamp = 1564562500699;
$milliseconds = $timestamp % (60*1000); // 40699
$timestampWithoutSeconds = $timestamp - $milliseconds;

// Your condition
```

If you want a Carbon solution looks like [subSeconds](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) used with [second](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) getter would work :

```
$carbon1->subSeconds($carbon1->second);
```

Comment: Just edited with a solution using Carbon. @tomloprod

Answer (score 2):

You can floor Carbon objects:

```
if ($carbon1->floorMinute() > $carbon2->floorMinute()) {
   // Do something...
}
```

Or `->roundMinute()` depending on you want the lower or the closest minute.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you